# Javascript Sort for Currency String

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript and would to know how to create syntax that will convert currency values that are in string format ($1,234.56) to numbers (1234.56) that can be sorted. Or is there perhaps a way of just sorting the values without removing the string format?

Comment: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/format-unformat-money-currency-javascript/

Comment: MDN has a pretty good [Javascript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Use string functions to remove the dollar sign and thousands separator. Read up on the array `.sort()` function to find out how to get it to do a numeric sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
var yourNumber = Number('$1,234.56'.replace(/(^\$|,)/g,''));
alert(yourNumber + 1);
```

`//` for javascript Regex

`\$` for `$`

`^\$` for `$` at the begin

`,` for `,`

`|` for `OR` operator

`g` for search all match

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Check the library [jquery-maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) which handles all of this for you.

It let's you do stuff like:

```
$('#yourNumberInput').maskMoney()
```

and if `yourNumberInput` had say, the value `1999.99` it would turn it into `$ 1.999,99`

You can also transform your input back and configure various formatting settings. (Note you need jquery in order to use it)

Comment: I strongly disagree with the idea that the OP should have installed jQuery and then a library which depends on it in order to solve this. This doesn't teach the OP to be more well-suited in the future. In a metaphorical sense, this is the equivalent of giving them a fish.